# WPF Effect prevent texture reloading

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, .net-4.6

I currently have an application which displays Images in a grid. Each image has an effect. When the user moves the mouse while clicked, some input parameters for the effect are changed, leading to a different display of the image. However when I have about 8 or more images displayed, and each image is changed simultaneously, I experience a large drop in FPS.

Using the Perforator tool, I noticed that the HW IRTs get very large (32 per frame for 8 images). The amount of HW IRTs is proportional to the amount of images displayed. So it seems that for each frame change, the Image texture is loaded again and again to the GPU, although the actual texture never changes.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour? RenderOptions.CachingHint sounded like a candidate for this, but it does not have any effect when I set it on the Image.

Comment: How many MouseMove events are you handling? Consider throttling the events, so that no more than 24 per second get triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried throttling so I have about 30 mouse move events per second, there is absolutely no difference.